# Complicated AVRO schema conversion to CSV using Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I have quite a complicated avro file (showing a small excerpt of `df.printSchema()`):

```
root
 |-- identifier: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- domain: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- version: long (nullable = true)
 |-- recordOperator: string (nullable = true)
 |-- payload: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- identity: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- domain: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- version: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- principalPaymentPeriodDates: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- frequency: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- frequency: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- issuer: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- schemeName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- count: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- firstRegularPeriodStartDate: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- lastRegularPeriodEndDate: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- startDate: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- endDate: string (nullable = true)
 ..........................
```

around 300 lines

I want to convert it into csv but when I use:

`df.write().option("header",true).format("csv").save("C:\\Users\\my_output.csv");`

I got this error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: CSV data source does not support structdomain:string,id:string,version:bigint data type.;

which I guess is expected. I have gone through other questions and some of the answers are around converting from array to string, etc. But for me, the schema is simply too huge to go around converting flatten out individual structs.

Is there a quick and dirty solution ?

Answer (score 0):

#### If you want to keep your schema as it is

You will have to use something different than CSV. CSV cannot store hierarchical data. I would recommend using JSON (unless you're talking very big files) because you can read those with a text editor (like CSV files).

#### If you're fine with changing the schema of your DF but really want to write a CSV file

You can flatten your structs like so (**disclaimer, you asked for quick and dirty :)**):

Say you start with the following schema (a subset of your schema to keep it simple):

```
root
 |-- identifier: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- domain: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- version: long (nullable = true)
 |-- payload: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- identity: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- domain: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- version: long (nullable = true)
```

Then you can unwrap your structs into something flat using `select("structCol.*")`. You can then prepend the name of the original hierarchical column (like `payload` and `identifier` in this example) to the child column names to keep the hierarchy in the names.

Doing this multiple times like so:

```py
df\
    .select("identifier.*", "payload.*")\
    .withColumnRenamed("domain", "identifierDomain")\
    .withColumnRenamed("id", "identifierId")\
    .withColumnRenamed("version", "identifierVersion")\
    .select("identity.*", "*")\
    .drop("identity")\
    .withColumnRenamed("domain", "payloadIdentityDomain")\
    .withColumnRenamed("id", "payloadIdentityId")\
    .withColumnRenamed("version", "payloadIdentityVersion")\
    .printSchema()
```

Gives you this schema at the end:

```
root
 |-- payloadIdentityDomain: string (nullable = true)
 |-- payloadIdentityId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- payloadIdentityVersion: long (nullable = true)
 |-- identifierDomain: string (nullable = true)
 |-- identifierId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- identifierVersion: long (nullable = true)
```

Which you can write as CSV